# Wemos mini уходит в ребут

Tags: esp8266

Плата Wemos mini d1 при загрузке любого скетча уходит в вечный ребут по разным причинам. Конкретно интересует следующее: проект  ([Alex Gyver Web lamp](https://alexgyver.ru/weblamp/))
На одну плату загрузился и работает без проблем, а на другой в порт кидает сообщение:

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,7)

wdt reset
load 0x4010f000, len 3584, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0xb0
csum 0xb0
v2843a5ac
~ld
```

Comment: Любой скетч? Даже самый простой blink? Типичная проблема - это недостаточное питание, в этом случае часто сбоит при включении wifi. Питания от USB далеко в этом случае не всегда хватает.

Comment: @RomanKonoval При блинке - светодиод светится, кратковременно гаснет и снова светится. После погасания в порте  ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

Да и при подключении внешнего БП 5В 2А те же симптомы
Также при работе заметил небольшое нагревание модуля в районе металлической крышечки (примерно 35-40 градусов)